# C# Adding classes with one another

Tags: c#, vector

So I was playing around with "Vectors" in C# I created my own Vector class.
What I tried to do was to add two vectors with each other by a simple "+". 
This is my vector class:

```
class createVector
{
    //My x,y,z coordinates
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int z { get; set; }

    //constructor
    public createVector(int X, int Y, int Z=0)
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        z = Z;
    }

    // Convert to String
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("X:{0,-5}\nY:{1,-5}\nZ:{2,-5}", x, y, z);
    }
 }
```

And what I attempted to do was this:

```
        createVector Vector1 = new createVector(1, 2);
        createVector Vector2 = new createVector(3, 4, 5);

        createVector Vector 3 = Vector1 + Vector2;
```

I don't want to use a function to add the Vectors together.

Is it possible for me to do something like this?

Comment: I don't know C#, but `+` likely *is* a function btw.

Comment: Please provide an example of two example vectors along with an example result vector so we know how you want the `+` to function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to overload the `+` operator inside the class:

```
public static Vector operator +(Vector v1, Vector v2) 
{
    // do logic here then return a vector
    return new Vector (); 
}
```

It is better to follow .NET naming conventions and have your class named `Vector` and not `createVector`. It should be a noun and using *PascalCase* .

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm still learning C# and will soon be doing .Net, just want to get over the basics